# how to detect if a link was clicked when window.onbeforeunload is triggered?

Tags: javascript

I have window.onbeforeunload triggering properly.  It's displaying a confirmation box to ensure the user knows they are navigating (closing) the window and that any unsaved work will be erased.

I have a unique situation where I don't want this to trigger if a user navigates away from the page by clicking a link, but I can't figure out how to detect if a link has been clicked inside the function to halt the function.  This is what I have for code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
var message = 'You are leaving the page.';

/* If this is Firefox */
if(/Firefox[\/\s](\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent) && new Number(RegExp.$1) >= 4) {
  if(confirm(message)) {
    history.go();
  } 
  else {
    window.setTimeout(function() {
      window.stop();
    }, 1);
  }
}
/* Everything else */
else {
  return message;
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You're looking for deferred event handling. I'll explain using jQuery, as it is less code:

```
window._link_was_clicked = false;
window.onbeforeunload = function(event) {
  if (window._link_was_clicked) {
    return; // abort beforeunload
  }
  // your event handling
};

jQuery(document).on('click', 'a', function(event) {
  window._link_was_clicked = true;
});
```

a (very) poor man's implementation without jQuery's convenient delegation handling could look like:

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  if (this.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    window._link_was_clicked = true;
  }
}, true);
```

this allows *all* links on your page to leave without invoking the `beforeunload` handler. I'm sure you can figure out how to customize this, should you only want to allow this for a specific set of links (your question wasn't particularly clear on that).

Comment: This is great thanks for the reply. I'm trying to use this without jQuery - and I'm trying to figure out how to integrate the poormans implementation but can't seem to figure it out (forgive me, I'm a bit of a JS newb).

Comment: Your code was semi-right. I've answered the question with the full answer.

Comment: If anyone have problem making it work in IE I had to return undefined instead of null. Works in both ie and chrome.

Comment: Re your second code block: `this` in that handler will always refer to `document`, which obviously will never be an `a` element. In 2013, you needed a loop starting in `event.target` and stopping at `this` and checking each element in-between. Here in 2018, on really up-to-date modern browsers, you can use the DOM's new `closest` function (which is very like jQuery's): `if (event.target.closest("a"))`...

Answer (score 5):

```
var link_was_clicked = false;
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'a') {
    link_was_clicked = true;
  }
}, true);

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
  if(link_was_clicked) {
    link_was_clicked = false;
    return;
  }
  //other code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can differ between a `link unload` or a `reload/user entering a different address unload` s by using a timer. This way you know the `beforeunload` was triggered directly after the link click.

Example using jQuery:

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  window.last_clicked_time = new Date().getTime();
  window.last_clicked = $(this);
});

$(window).bind('beforeunload', function() {
  var time_now = new Date().getTime();
  var link_clicked = window.last_clicked != undefined;
  var within_click_offset = (time_now - window.last_clicked_time) < 100;

  if (link_clicked && within_click_offset) {
    return 'You clicked a link to '+window.last_clicked[0].href+'!';
  } else {
    return 'You are leaving or reloading the page!';
  }
});
```

(tested in Chrome)

Comment: IE, Edge, Firefox ?