# JS disable beforeunload event handler for a specific case

Tags: javascript, html

I have an event handler for the `beforeunload` window event.

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", myScript);
```

I also have an `A` tag which his `href` is a download file link. So when I click on the link the browser file download popup opens and it causes the `beforeunload` to get fire. How can I prevent this from this specific link?

```
 <a href="link">Download</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

open a new tab

```
<a href="link" target="_blank">Download</a>
```

Comment: I need it to be on this tab.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15277403/how-to-detect-if-a-link-was-clicked-when-window-onbeforeunload-is-triggered

Comment: @undefined,duplicate ,please delete this post

Comment: I can't, remove your answer.